# How to merge two parts of conic-gradients in the background?

Tags: html, css, conic-gradients

As a green hand in front-end, recently I was stuck in designing a single webpage. Here is my rendering of what I want:

[rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eRAh.jpg)

What is needed to be emphasized is that the background should fit browser fully, without scoller bars. Here I use two face-to-face conic-gradients to create a "platform".

It may be not difficult for pros, but I could just not figure it out. Thanks in advance.